# Core Java What is Wrong with this Simple Syntax

Tags: java, final, primitive

I have a code like this.

```
public void test()
{
    final boolean passDay = true;
    final int status;
    //if the right side takes place means i need status value below and is set
    //if only the left side is takes place i dont care about status because i will not use it 
    if(!passDay && ((status=loadStatusValue()))== Constants.YORK_CORK_EMPTY_SET)
        System.out.println("inside 1");//I DONT CARE ABOUT STATUS VALUE
    else
    {
        if(passDay)System.out.println("BAMBA");//I DONT CARE ABOUT STATUS VALUE
        else
        {  
            //HERE STATUS ALWAYS WILL HOLD A VALUE SIMPLYBECAUSE RIGHT SIDE
            //IS ALREADY EVALUATED BECAUSE passDay=false and !passDay=true
            System.out.println(status);            
            //I MEAN I USE STATUS ONLY AFTER BEING INITIALIZED  
            //WHY variable status might not have been initialized IS SHOW IF I AM HERE IS BECAUSE STATUS HAS A VALUE.
        }
    }                
}
private boolean compute(){return true;}
private int loadStatusValue(){return Constants.BOTH_YORK_CORK_SET;}
```

What i think in this method everything works i use the status int variable when was already set even is not defined in the initialization.

As you can see the passDay is a boolean means only could hold true or false i have try hardcoded with true and false and not compilation error is show when shows a compilation error when instead being hardcode i do something like it.

```
final boolean passDay = compute();
```

in fact compute is also returning a boolean could be true or false but in this case a compilation error is show **variable status might not have been initialized** but can't java realize that even when true status is just not used and when false the status variable is initialized or set it and used later or i am wrong?

Comment: no, unlike class variables local variables have to be initialized before using them. Otherwise you will run into a compiler error.

Comment: but i am using status only after initialization in this example.. i use only status in System.out.println(status); and in this step status always has a value..

Comment: @chiperortiz not necessarily - `&&` short-circuits evaluation if the LHS is false.

Answer (score 4):

Please read about short circuit evaluation in Java - 
(condition1 && condition2).

The condition preceding the && operator if evaluates to false; the execution does not evaluate the other condition as it is not required. Regardless of the output of condition2 - false && condition2 shall evaluate to false. Try rearranging the order of conditions or initialize the variable first.

hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the issue here though, if the first condition short-circuits the evaluation the `passDay` reference is not used. The problem is more likely that the compiler can't figure this out due to the complicated code structure.

Comment: But what is wrong is right side is not evaluated? status is not set i know but if the right side of the condition is not evaluated means i will not use the status variable below and i dont care about status anymore..

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is a short-circuiting operator. This means that in the following expression:

```
!passDay && ((status=loadStatusValue()))== Constants.YORK_CORK_EMPTY_SET
```

The right-hand operand (`((status=loadStatusValue()))== Constants.YORK_CORK_EMPTY_SET`) is only evaluated if `!passDay` is `true`. This means that the assignment of `status` will only take place if `passDay` is false.

If you use `final boolean passDay = compute();`, there is no way of knowing at compile time if `compute()` will return true or false.

I suspect (without having tried it) that your code will compile with `compute()` if you use the non-short-circuiting AND operator, `&`, which will evaluate the right-hand operand even if the left-hand operand is false.

---

I think that a better approach is just to restructure your code to make this conditional more readable. Conditionals with side effects are error-prone because it is very easy to overlook the side effect when reading the code:

```
if (passDay) {
  System.out.println("BAMBA");
} else {
  status = loadStatusValue();
  if (status == Constants.YORK_CORK_EMPTY_SET) {
    System.out.println("inside 1");
  } else {
    System.out.println(status);
  }
}
```

Comment: yep it works using &. I understand about circuiting but what i am trying to do if the status variable is used below i mean System.out.println(status) if this step is take place the status variable always will hold a value because is set ((status=loadStatusValue()) if is not set i not use it because is not required.

Comment: I suspect you are over-estimating the depth of the static analysis done to determine if a variable is definitely assigned in any given branch.

Comment: My code is used because is more difficult and this is a simple example about it...

Answer (score 1):

Within your code, you set `passDay` to `final` meaning it's value can **never** be changed throughout program execution. Bear this in mind whenever you're doing conditional checks, such as `if(!passDay ... )` etc.

If you expect, or intend, to have the value `passDay` changed, then you can initialise to `true` at the start of execution, but don't delcare as `final`

Hopefully this clears some things up.

Comment: This doesn't account for why `final boolean passDay = true` works but `final boolean passDay = compute()` does not.